# How do I fade out a circle in a Google Map, x seconds after I've added it to the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

What I basically had in mind is what Google did in [this](http://www.morethanamap.com/demos/visualization/earthquakes) example

Every second I want to add circles at certain coordinates and then slowly fade them out. I already managed to add circles to the map:

```
var citymap = {};
citymap['chicago'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  population: 100
};
citymap['amsterdam'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.878113, 5.629798),
  population: 40
};
citymap['paris'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.9021449, 2.4699208),
  population: 100
};
citymap['moscow'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.021369, 37.9650909),
  population: 100
};
citymap['newyork'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.9152414, -73.70027209999999),
  population: 80
};
citymap['losangeles'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.3373061, -118.1552891),
  population: 65
}

for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#900057",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#900057",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        clickable: false,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: citymap[city].population * 2000
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
}
```

But I can't find how to fade them out anywhere. Already tried going through the Google Maps API documentation and even the example's code, but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fade them out you need to decrease the opacity of the fill and the stroke until it is 0.0.

```
setInterval(fadeCityCircles,1000);

function fadeCityCircles() {
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var fillOpacity = citymap[city].cityCircle.get("fillOpacity");
    fillOpacity -= 0.02;
    if (fillOpacity < 0) fillOpacity =0.0;
    var strokeOpacity = citymap[city].cityCircle.get("strokeOpacity");
    strokeOpacity -= 0.05;
    if (strokeOpacity < 0) strokeOpacity =0.0;
    citymap[city].cityCircle.setOptions({fillOpacity:fillOpacity, strokeOpacity:strokeOpacity});
  }
}
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_circleFade.html)