# Google Maps Circles Animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm developing a script to encourage the growth / reduction of the radius of a circle in the Google Maps API. But only 1 circle is the one that is animated, first I scroll the array drawing the circles in the map followed by I give animation (reduction and enlargement) of the radius. The solution might be to include an interval within the loop. I look forward to your help, thank you.

```js
    function initialize() {
    var _radius = 500;
    var rMin = _radius * 4/5;
    var rMax = _radius;
    var direction = 1;
 
       
        var citymap = {  chicago: {    center: {lat: -12.008711, lng: -77.053376} },  newyork: {  center: {lat: -12.01075, lng: -77.070083} },  losangeles: { center: {lat: -12.005359, lng: -77.06835} },  vancouver: { center: {lat: -11.990886, lng: -77.068101} }};
        var mapOptions = {
            center: {lat:  -12.004129, lng: -77.056904},
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                        mapOptions);
        
    for (var city in citymap) {
            var circleOption = {
        center: citymap[city].center,
        fillColor: '#3878c7',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        map: map,
        radius: 500,
        strokeColor: '#3878c7',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 0.5
    };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOption);
    }
      
        var circleTimer = setInterval(function(){
        var radius = circle.getRadius();
        
        if ((radius > rMax) || (radius < rMin)) {
            direction *= -1;
        }        
        var _par = (radius/_radius)-0.7;
        
        circleOption.radius = radius + direction * 10;
        circleOption.fillOpacity = 0.6 * _par;
        
        circle.setOptions(circleOption);
    }, 20);
    } 
  
  
  

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map { height: 90%; width: 90% }
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<!--script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script-->
    
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You
Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fade In circles in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235674/fade-in-circles-in-google-maps)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fade out a circle in a Google Map, x seconds after I've added it to the map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052580/how-do-i-fade-out-a-circle-in-a-google-map-x-seconds-after-ive-added-it-to-the)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circle fade out over time on Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198415/circle-fade-out-over-time-on-google-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only create the setInterval function for the last "city" whose circle you create.  One option for solving this is to use function closure to associate the setInterval function and the circle:

```
for (var city in citymap) {
  createCircle(citymap[city], map);
}

function createCircle(city, map) {
  var _radius = 500;
  var rMin = _radius * 4 / 5;
  var rMax = _radius;
  var direction = 1;
  var circleOption = {
    center: city.center,
    fillColor: '#3878c7',
    fillOpacity: 0.6,
    map: map,
    radius: 500,
    strokeColor: '#3878c7',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 0.5
  };
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOption);

  var circleTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var radius = circle.getRadius();

    if ((radius > rMax) || (radius < rMin)) {
      direction *= -1;
    }
    var _par = (radius / _radius) - 0.7;

    circleOption.radius = radius + direction * 10;
    circleOption.fillOpacity = 0.6 * _par;

    circle.setOptions(circleOption);
  }, 20);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/708L0eyd/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {

  var citymap = {
    chicago: {
      center: {
        lat: -12.008711,
        lng: -77.053376
      },
      fillColor: "red"
    },
    newyork: {
      center: {
        lat: -12.01075,
        lng: -77.070083
      },
      fillColor: "blue"
    },
    losangeles: {
      center: {
        lat: -12.005359,
        lng: -77.06835
      },
      fillColor: "green"
    },
    vancouver: {
      center: {
        lat: -11.990886,
        lng: -77.068101
      },
      fillColor: "orange"
    }
  };
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: -12.004129,
      lng: -77.056904
    },
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

  for (var city in citymap) {
    createCircle(citymap[city], map);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function createCircle(city, map) {
  var _radius = 500;
  var rMin = _radius * 4 / 5;
  var rMax = _radius;
  var direction = 1;
  var circleOption = {
    center: city.center,
    fillColor: city.fillColor,
    fillOpacity: 0.6,
    map: map,
    radius: 500,
    strokeColor: '#3878c7',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 0.5
  };
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOption);

  var circleTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var radius = circle.getRadius();

    if ((radius > rMax) || (radius < rMin)) {
      direction *= -1;
    }
    var _par = (radius / _radius) - 0.7;

    circleOption.radius = radius + direction * 10;
    circleOption.fillOpacity = 0.6 * _par;

    circle.setOptions(circleOption);
  }, 20);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```